# Problem understanding some parts in a sentence －てくの and －んだろうって

Tags: grammar

The sentence is this one:

> 私は立場的に何を着**てくの**が正しい**んだろうって**思って。。。

I think I got the rough meaning of the sentence: I (私) am wondering (思って) what's (何を) is the right thing (が正し) to wear (着) for her position (立場的に).

But, I'm still puzzled over the meaning of the bolded parts.

Comment: What is the overall context of this sentence? *(Where does it come from?)* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

私は立場的に何を着ていくのが正しいのだろうと思って

着てく = 着ていく = 着て行く = wear + go

んだろうって = のだろう + casual って quotation particle

After that it's pretty simple!

Answer (score 1):

In the text-like style:
私は自分の立場として何を着ていくことが正しいのだろうかと思って・・・

More literarily:
私は自分の立場として何を着ていくことが正しいことなのだろうかと考えて・・・

Because "～的に" is used, the speaker will be a young person. About "着てくのが" I can tell you two things: one is that many Japanese drop "い" from "～ていく" in a usual conversation, and the other is that "の" in front of particles is the same as "こと". Two things About "正しいんだろうって": one is that "ん" is a euphonic change form of the particle "の", and the other is that most Japanese use "って" instead of "と" in a usual conversation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations on spoken Japanese. You are right about the speaker being a young person (high school girl).

Answer (score 1):

(I'm not sure what is puzzling you but...) I think the sentence can also be written as:

> 『私は立場的に何を着てくのが正しいんだろう？』って思って・・・

- 立場的に is like [立場上]{たちばじょう}, "considering my position / status, or relationship to other people who attend the occasion." To me, 立場的に sounds a bit more casual than 立場上.
- 着てく is a colloquial, shortened version of 着て行く, "wear and go" or "wear and attend (the occasion)".
- The の is a nominalizer. (See: [verb nominalization の](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles#no)) Here it nominalizes the verb 着てく, so that it can be followed by the case particle が.
- The ん in 正しいんだろう is the colloquial version of the nominalization particle の. The subject for 正しい is (私が)何を着て行くこと, "What for me to wear for the occasion."

  It has the same structure as (and a similar meaning to):

> 「私は立場上、何を着て行くことが適切なのだろうか？」と思って・・・。

Comment: @ssb answered my question first (so I accepted his), but thanks for the thorough explanation of the sentence. It was really helpful. どうもありがとう！