# What does the く in 無くしてく do?

Tags: て-form

In the song [深い森](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIoDWTF0qSo) by Do As Infinity, this comes up:

```
僕たちは 生きるほどに
失くしてく 少しずつ
偽りや 嘘をまとい
```

Is this 失くしてく a short-form of 失くしていく?
Or is the く after the て-form of 失くす　something else?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30995/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11745/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this 失くしてく a short-form of 失くしていく?

Quick answer: Yes.

An English translation [here](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%E6%B7%B1%E3%81%84%E6%A3%AE-deep-forest.html) also shows that it must be ていく because it shows the progression of losing something

```
As we go on living
We lose something little by little
Wrapped in deceit and lies
```