# What does this "く” mean?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, song-lyrics, music

Context: in a song that I think is about love or relationships in some way, "♪生まれて 育ってくサークル" was a lyric. I was wondering what the "く" before "サークル" was...maybe a shortened version of a verb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem understanding some parts in a sentence －てくの and －んだろうって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11745/problem-understanding-some-parts-in-a-sentence-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%ae-and-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6)

Answer (score 2):

It's short for 育っていく. Very often in speech XXている and XXていく are abbreviated into XXてる and XXてく.

> 生まれて **育ってく**サークル
> The circle that is born and **will grow up(get raised)**

Without further context, this is as much of a translation as I can do.